# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale when using ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, plot, format

I plotted a scatterplot with the amount of frequency on the y-axis and the date (e.g. 2012-07) on the x-axis. Also, I added vertical lines to the plot (vector r1). After plotting, I get the error message

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

My dataframe **df1** looks like this:

```
date         amount
2012-07          2
2012-08          4
2012-09          4
2012-10          3
2012-11          2
2012-12          3
2013-01          5 
2013-02          4
2013-03          3
2013-04          2
2013-05          1
2013-06          4
2013-07          3
```

And my vertical lines are in the vector r1 and look like this:

```
1
2
4
6
7
9
```

The number 1 is equal to my first entry of df1$date, the number 2 is the second entry and so on.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=date,y=amount, color=gr)) +    
            geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(r1), alpha=0.5) +    
            geom_point()
```

I guess the error comes from the fact, that r1 has values like 1, 2, 5 but my x-axis is in date format, which doesn't fit together.  So the number 1 represents my first date in vector r1, 2 the second date and so on....Is there any way I can change this r1 vetor into my corresponding dates? Thanks!

Comment: Please add some sample data as to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: @beetroot I just edited how my data looks like

Comment: Do you mean you x-axis is in a date format? Please update the ggplot-call with your column names from your example df

Comment: @kath sorry for the mistakes, I hope its all correct now

Comment: For me it works if you switch `geom_point` and `geom_vline`: `ggplot(df1, aes(date, amount)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept = r1, alpha = 0.5)`

Comment: I assume your date column is not in a proper date format but is a factor (or converted to it when used in `ggplot` as x-axis), thus this approach works but might be producing wrong results due to different ordering of the data. I guess it might be better to convert the date column in  a date format and change r1 as well to the actual dates.

Comment: The error comes from the `df1`, not from `r1`. The `date` column is not in a proper date format. Try setting the date to e.g. the first of each month: `2012-07-01`. Also, you should change `color=gr` to `color='gr'`. And by using `xintercept=df1$date[r1]` you can use the values in `r1` as pointers to rows in `df1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by transforming your date column into a propoer formatted date with `as.Date`. As only the moth is available I set the day to be the first of the month but you could also specify the 15th.

```
df1$date <- as.Date(paste0(df1$date, "-01"))
```

When we now plot the data, the x-axis is formatted nicely:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(date, amount)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

For the vertical lines, extract the required dates from the data.frame and thenn add them to the plot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(date, amount)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = df1$date[r1], alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

It also works now if you switch the order of the calls

```
ggplot(df1, aes(date, amount)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = df1$date[r1], alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point()
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- 
  structure(list(date = c("2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", 
                          "2012-12", "2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", 
                          "2013-05", "2013-06", "2013-07"), 
                 amount = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

r1 <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

As kath mentions it is probably best to change the date and the lines into a date format. Here I use the `lubridate` package

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
"date         amount
2012-07          2
2012-08          4
2012-09          4
2012-10          3
2012-11          2
2012-12          3
2013-01          5 
2013-02          4
2013-03          3
2013-04          2
2013-05          1
2013-06          4
2013-07          3"
)

r1 <- c(1,2,4,6,7,9)

df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(line = ifelse(row_number(date) %in% r1, date, NA)) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date, truncated = 2), line = ymd(line, truncated = 2))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = date,y = amount, color = amount)) +    
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = line), alpha=0.5) +    
  geom_point()
```

Note: I changed the `col` argument to `amount` since `gr` wasn't in the sample data.